# How do I keep previous form entry when the user attaches a file

Tags: javascript, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a form and it has an attachment button, is it possible to keep the entries they entered when they hit the attach file button and it refreshes? The inputs are all dropdowns, i'm not exactly sure how I should start with this..

Comment: How about providing some code? If page is getting refreshed, you cannot save any data with JavaScript.

Comment: It's for a forum, mybb. They have an attachment plugin which I use but when I use it, it always refreshes the page when attaching. The submitted fields then goes blank.

Comment: @Radio: Yes, you can save data with javascript in a variety of ways -- cookies, ajax, etc.

Comment: @GeneAllisterSy: Something doesn't seem like its wired up right if your page is refreshing every time you "attach" a file to your form. Please post code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to catch the entries on the server and when you push the next page back to the client set the entries to be the same.

Or you could use some client side local storage to store the settings before the postback occurs and set them again on next page reload.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this.  The simplest way is to simply store the form values in a cookie when the form is submitted using the [form.onSubmit](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp) event.  Essentially, you just read the values from the form into the cookie, and then when the page is refreshed, read them out of the cookie and back into the form.  [Example here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/setcookie/).